# Angular 8 - How to add active class to an a tag which doesn't has any router link

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am creating Submenus in my Angular project.

The requirement is that when we click on a menu and if it has a child Menu then expand it. So When a child menu link is active and we collapse the Parent menu then the Parent menu should Have the **active class** on it. so that we know this parent menu's child link is opened therefor it is **highlighted**.

In my case when I collapse the Parent Menu the **active class removes** from the parent menu and it is hard to identify which menu link's page is opened.

For example: Before collapsing
[image: Before Collapsing]

after Collapsing -[image: After Collapsing]

Code -
HTML Template

```
      <nav>
      <ul>
          <li>
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/dashboard/report" #dashboard="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active">
                  <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_icon site_sidebar-main_link--dashboard"></span>
                  <span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Dashboard</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/dashboard/allocate" #capacityPlanning="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active">
                  <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_icon site_sidebar-main_link--task"></span>
                  <span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Capacity Planning</span>
              </a>
          </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" expandMenu>
                    <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_icon site_sidebar-main_link--dashboard"></span>
                    <span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Projects Master</span>
                    <span class="fa fa-lg fa-caret-left site_sidebar-main_down-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse submenu" id="pageSubmenu">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/project/list" #projects="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active">
                        <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_icon site_sidebar-main_link--bu"> </span>
                        <span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Projects list</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/resource/list" #resource="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active">
                        <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_link--resources"></span><span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Resources</span>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </li>
          <li>
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/team-type/list" #team="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active">
                  <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_icon site_sidebar-main_link--team"></span><span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Team type</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/team/list" #resource="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active">
                  <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_icon site_sidebar-main_link--resources"></span><span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Team</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/projectType/list" #resource="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active">
                  <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_icon site_sidebar-main_link--resources"></span><span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Project Type</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/region/list" #resource="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active">
                  <span class="fa fa-lg site_sidebar-main_icon site_sidebar-main_link--resources"></span><span class="site_sidebar-main_link-title">Regions</span>
              </a>
          </li>

      </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS -

```
ul li a.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: px2rem(30) 0 0 px2rem(30);
    color: blue !important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
ul li a.active > .site_sidebar-main_down-icon{
  transform: rotate(270deg);
} 

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}
 .submenu{
   padding-left: px2rem(15);
 }
```

Now I want to add here that when any child menu link is opened and if we collapse the parent menu then keep the parent menu class active (highlighted).

Any suggestion on how to achieve this implementation is welcome.

Comment: When you use `routerLinkActive="active"` You're telling Angular that add the class "active" if the link meet the `routerLink` property. You can use this behaivor by defect if not override the class.active with your directive -simply use another name for one of the class-

Comment: If your URL structure supports it you can set `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
false}" ` on the `master` link and this would match both `/master` and `/master/capacity-planning`

Comment: Master is used just to show the child links. It is not redirecting to any page. So I need to make it active when the child links are active otherwise it should not add active to the master. @SamScholefield